# Power an Arduino Nano with the 5V port and use an LED

Tags: arduino, batteries, infrared

I have an infrared LED that uses the 5V port for power. However, I've read that you need to use the 5V pin to use AA batteries. Is it possible to wire the LED or the batteries to a different pin, or do I need to stick to USB power?

Comment: Any reason you can't connect both to the 5V pin?

Comment: So power can go in the 5V and out of it too? In that case, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: usb is 5v too, you can use it if in doubt.

Comment: USB wouldn't drain the battery any more than connect to the 5V pin, right?

Comment: Yes, you can connect both to the 5V pin (with a current limiting resistor for the LED). The LED will always be on in this case though. Is that what you want? Or do you want the ability to turn the LED on and off?

Comment: I need to be able to control the LED using the Arduino. Does that mean I need to use another way to power it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543073/does-my-ir-led-need-a-ground/543075), I can just rewire the LED to use Ground instead. As a result, the 5v pin is now free for the AA batteries.